# Laravel: Getting extra column (from other model) in eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

-- What do i expect --

I am in progress of filling a form select based on the selection of another select.

The first select is:

```
{{Form::select('country',$countries,$player->city->country->id,['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'selectCountry'])}}
```

The Second select should fill the cities that are linked to the country.

-- My controller trying to receive necesarry info--

```
return Country::find($request->get('country'))->cities->where('player_id','!=',null);
```

And this all works fine. Now here is the issue, my JSON object (the model Country) has a player_id, but i want the result to also include the 'player_name' column that he finds in the App\Player model.

Anyone has an idea how to build up the Eloquent query? Or can it only be done by a DB:: query, if so how do i build up this query?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a player_id column on the Country table, you should have a player() relation on the Country model.

So you can do :

```
return Country::find($request->get('country'))->cities->where('player_id','!=',null)->with('player');
```

And then `$country->player->player_name`;

Comment: I get this error message:
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist.

Comment: Ok, your code was nearly right but it needs the each before the with so: